# List View error in the fragment - imageLoader

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, fragment, android-volley

i'm trying to change my project from activity to fragment

i did all the changing i need to make it work but it still not working win the application is running
and i edit the code as the help i get here but still , the application crash once the fragment start
my new fragment code is :

`

public class DessertsShow extends Fragment {

```
int counter = 0;

// Log tag
private static final String TAG = "lol";

// Movies json url
private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;

public DessertsShow(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dessertshow, container, false);

    return rootView;
}




@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("fargment test", "1 ");
    listView =(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    Log.d("fargment test", "2 ");
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    Log.d("fargment test", "3 ");
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d("fargment test", "4 ");
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // new Loadmore().execute();
            Log.d("fargment test", "5 ");
            loadList(counter);
        }
    });
    Log.d("fargment test", "6 ");
    loadList(counter);
}





public void loadList(int i)
{
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();
    // changing action bar color
    getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));
    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    int subcounter = counter +3;
                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = counter; i < (subcounter); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                    counter = counter + 3 ;
                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    hidePDialog();

                }
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
}
```

## }`

i guess the problem is with the imageLoader 
here is my CustomListAdapter class

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Movie> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // rating
    rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

    // genre
    String genreStr = "";
    for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
        genreStr += str + ", ";
    }
    genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
            genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
    genre.setText(genreStr);

    // release year
    year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

    return convertView;
}
```

}

and here AppController class

```
public class AppController extends Application {

public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

private static AppController mInstance;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mInstance = this;
}

public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
    return mInstance;
}

public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    getRequestQueue();
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                new LruBitmapCache());
    }
    return this.mImageLoader;
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    req.setTag(TAG);
    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
```

}

i know the problem is that the class are made for Activity not fragment 
but i couldn't convert them right ... any help in the code pleas

"the error start here " 
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

Comment: post stacktrace to get more help

Comment: What's on line 137 of DessertsShow.java

Comment: 133 : counter = counter + 3 ;
136 :  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
137 :    }

Comment: here the full code       
https://www.mediafire.com/?qxcd856pxkk4ym1

Comment: You have a NPE at DessertsShow.java:137. So if that line is } I'm guessing that you pasted the wrong stack trace.

Comment: im sure i pasted the right one .... plz download the full code i provided and see where the wrong is ... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to onActivityCreated

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("fargment test", "0 ");
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dessertshow, container, false);
    return rootView;
}
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("fargment test", "1 ");
    listView =(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.list);
    Log.d("fargment test", "2 ");
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
    Log.d("fargment test", "3 ");
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    Log.d("fargment test", "4 ");
    listView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // new Loadmore().execute();
            Log.d("fargment test", "5 ");
            loadList(counter);
        }
    });
    Log.d("fargment test", "6 ");
    loadList(counter);
}
```

Comment: Good catch. Check out the fragment lifecycle diagram [here](https://github.com/xxv/android-lifecycle) to see that `onActivityCreated` is indeed called after `onCreateView`.

Comment: If you found the solution helpful vote up and if it solved your problem make sure you mark it as answer.

Comment: thank you for your help 
that solved one problem , but even so i once the fragment start the application crash .
i deleted every thing in the fragment. 
the listview , the adapter ..every thing 
 but the loadList() method , it still crash even if i didn't call the method !

Comment: "getActivity() is null on onCreateView()." not it's not. `getActivity()` is valid between `onAttach(Activity)` and `onDetach()`. Check the diagram, it's the first and last call.

Comment: @Budius is right.  getActivity() should always return non-null from onCreateView.

Comment: Glad to know you are all trying to give the solution to the OP ;)